# IR remote code amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, relay, infrared

I am interested in amplifying output mod signal of my tv remote in order to use a higher power led/vcsel. Now, it should be as simple as cutting the emitter led and putting a transistor that would close the external circuit (I mean not part of the circuit outside of the remote controller) when there's voltage differential, and the rest of it is easy - a dc power supply, led/laser driver and a 940nm emitter with some optics - 1-3 A emitter instead of 20mA - that's the idea.

Basically just fast switching capable... something. Right?

If all of the above checks out, I actually need help choosing the transistor, or another way to do this (audio amplifier module?)

I'm a flashlight/laser fan and electronics noob ;D
Hope you guys can help out?

Comment: You can buy a laser driver online with a TTL input for a few dollars.  Unless you want to DIY this to I would buy a suitable driver for your laser and then wire the controller signal directly to the laser modulation input.  I think at most you might need some level shifting (e.g. 3.3 to 5v).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I'd have to boost the output to 5v though, since 940nm leds work with 1.6V at 20mA.

Comment: A good remote with dual 100mA LEDs if tuned properly for carrier f with fresh batteries should already work 30m or off all the walls in a room. But you need to know all the values of ESR

Comment: User1850479, I checked out some of these laser drivers with TTL, they are mostly limited to 20kHz, while most of the remote controllers use 38kHz for emitter. I have no idea if that's a problem, since switching frequency is a lot lower.

Comment: Tony, I would like to test the limits of technology, I already have a vscel in mind, it's an Osram 940nm emitter, already tested in t20 flashlight, this plano-convex lens makes things visible to camera without ir filter over 1km, driven at 2.5A. Old fashion dot lasers are also an option. I'm doing it for fun, and I want to learn, not just have a good quality remote.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to disconnect the existing LED -- it will have a ~ 2 V pulsing signal across it that you can use.

Comment: Thanks jp314, But forward voltage of the original emitter is just 1.6V. I thought I'd have to draw some current to boost it to 5V to connect to the ttl (in the above mentioned case). But, if I cut the led, then it's gonna push about 3.2V (or whatever two AAs in series got), because it's not limiting it to 10-20-30mA, and I figured 3V might be already enough? Or at least converted to 5V, in which case I need to draw some current, right? I can already see how simple this is too all you guys. But it's not simple for me 